# AFHTTPSessionManager Delegate issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

here is my issue:
I have a `AFHTTPSessionManager` file, which is also a singleton, and manage all my API requests to my server. Once I got the answer from the server with a `responseObject`, I pass it back to the `UIViewController` who asked for it using a delegate.

My problem is : since my manager is a singleton, if another API request is made in the meantime by another `UIViewController`, the delegate is set to this controller and when my first request `responseObject` is received I can't pass it back to the first `UIViewController` anymore.

I hope it's easy to understand.

What would be the right way to solve this problem ?

Here is what a method looks like in my `AFHTTPSessionManager` class :

```
- (void)getStaffForCompany:(int)companyID
{
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"currentUser"])
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        parameters[@"apiKey"] = agendizeApiKey;
        parameters[@"token"] = [[AGZUserManager sharedAGZUser] currentApplicationUser].token;

        [self GET:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"scheduling/companies/%d/staff", companyID] parameters:parameters success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
            if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(AGZClient:successedReceiveStaffList:)]) {
                [self.delegate AGZClient:self successedReceiveStaffList:responseObject];
            }
        } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
            if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(AGZClient:failedReceiveStaffList:)]) {
                [self.delegate AGZClient:self failedReceiveStaffList:error];
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show some of your code? - You should probably consider using completion blocks so that you don't have to rely on setting the delegate every time.

Comment: I do have completion blocks, but i use a delegate to pass back the responseObject to the accurate Controller (I edited my question with some code)

Comment: Yeah, you should/could use completion blocks to send the responseObject back to the controller too.

Comment: Could you show me some code sample of how to do it please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define your own completion block and pass your responseObject back to the controller, here is an example `CustomCompletion`.

Add this to your `AFHTTPSessionManager.h` just above the `@implementation` line.

```
typedef void(^CustomCompletion)(id responseObject);
```

Update your method to include the `CustomCompletion` object.

```
- (void)getStaffForCompany:(int)companyID withCompletion:(CustomCompletion)completion {
    // On success pass the responseObject back like so.
    completion(responseObject);
}
```

Then `where all the magic happens`, back in your controller call this method on your singleton and handle the completion.

```
[SingletonManager getStaffForCompany:1 withCompletion:^(id responseObject) {
    if (responseObject) {
        // do something with this object
    }
}];
```

I haven't tested this code, but I do something very similar in `Swift` and it works a treat.

Comment: Looks great, one more thing as I'm not really familiar with blocks, where do you put this line of code :

typedef void(^CustomCompletion)(id responseObject);

?

Comment: Probably best to put it at the top of your `AFHTTPSessionManager.h` just above your `@implementation` - This way it is always included when you need it.